# mysqldump with create database if not exist for 1 table

Tags: mysql, command-line-arguments

As the subject suggests, I'm trying to use mysqldump to create a file that includes

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS
```

but only output a **single** table. I've tried multiple combinations of --databases, --tables, etc., but I can't get it to add the IF NOT EXISTS part at all (it's there but commented-out), and it only seems to work for outputting ALL the tables. Is it possible?

Some things I've tried:

Adds CREATE DATABASE (but not the IF NOT EXISTS part) but outputs ALL the tables:

```
mysqldump --host=<host> --user=<u> --password=<p> --port=<port> --verbose --single-transaction --add-drop-table --create-options --databases BBI > outfile.sql
```

Outputs the 1 table but no CREATE DATABASE:

```
mysqldump --host=<host> --user=<u> --password=<p> --port=<port> --verbose --single-transaction --add-drop-table --create-options BBI table1 > outfile.sql
```

gives error:

```
mysqldump --host=<host> --user=<u> --password=<p> --port=<port> --verbose --single-transaction --add-drop-table --create-options --databases BBI.table1 > outfile.sql
```

Would I have to resort to using the

```
--ignore-table=<table>
```

option for every table one I don't want? That would be a huge pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a workaround. The commands above were being executed from a PHP script using exec(). I changed the script to first do a

```
show create database BBI
```

query. It then modifies the statement returned from that to add the IF NOT EXISTS part and the USE BBI; statement. Then it runs the 2nd mysqldump statement above that outputs the 1 table but has no CREATE DATABASE. It then prepends the CREATE DATABASE statement to the beginning of the output file from mysqldump and everything works.